# How to display a spinner before a JavaScript file is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I have a Shiny app which load a huge JavaScript file (>17Mo). I'd like show a spinner until the JavaScript file is loaded. That does not work with **shinybusy**: the spinner only appears after the JS file has been loaded.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinybusy)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_sidebar(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "HUGE_JAVASCRIPT_FILE.js")
  ),
  
  busy_start_up(
    loader = spin_epic("orbit", color = "#FFF"),
    text = "Loading...",
    timeout = 1500,
    color = "#FFF",
    background = "#112446"
  ),
  
  title = "Gröbner implicitization with GIAC",
  
  sidebar = sidebar(
    textInput(
      "equations",
      "Equations: ",
      value = "x = a*cost, y = b*sint"
    ),
    textInput(
      "relations",
      "Relations: ",
      value = "cost^2 + sint^2 = 1"
    ),
    textInput(
      "symbols",
      "Symbols: ",
      value = "cost, sint, a, b"
    ),
    actionButton("go", "Run", class = "btn-primary")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the `defer` property and you can use the `onload` property to run some code once it is loaded, for instance `Shiny.setInputValue` to notify the server to close the spinner. We just have to introduce a small delay (`setTimeout`) , to make sure the `Shiny` framework is loaded (if somebody finds a solution which does not require this hack, I would be very happy to learn).

### Setup

```r
library(here)
library(data.table)

dir.create("www")
fn <- here("www", "larger.js")
fwrite(list(c(rep("console.log(1);", 2.5e4), "alert('done');")), fn)
```

### Folder Structure

```
.
├── app.R
└── www
    └── larger.js
```

### Code

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinybusy)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_sidebar(
   tags$head(
      tags$script(HTML("function done() {
                         setTimeout(() => Shiny.setInputValue('done', true), 100)
                       }")),
      tags$script(src = "larger.js", defer = NA, onload = "done()")
   ),
   busy_start_up(
      loader = spin_epic("orbit", color = "#FFF"),
      text = "Loading...",
      mode = "manual",
      color = "#FFF",
      background = "#112446"
   ),
   
   title = "Gröbner implicitization with GIAC",
   
   sidebar = sidebar(
      textInput(
         "equations",
         "Equations: ",
         value = "x = a*cost, y = b*sint"
      ),
      textInput(
         "relations",
         "Relations: ",
         value = "cost^2 + sint^2 = 1"
      ),
      textInput(
         "symbols",
         "Symbols: ",
         value = "cost, sint, a, b"
      ),
      actionButton("go", "Run", class = "btn-primary")
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observeEvent(input$done, 
                remove_start_up())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! You don't need to do something to remove the spinner, it is automatically removed whenever Shiny is not busy.

Comment: Well, you said you want ot remove it once the JS is loaded. I assume `shiny` is not busy when you load the script defered (that's in fact the very idea of defered that it does not block the rest). Maybe, `shiny` realizes it somehow, but in any case with this approch you have a way to react nonetheless.

Comment: thothal> I swear, Shiny is busy. This is what I observed.

Comment: Funny, I could also have sworn it did not work when I tried out, bu apparently it does. So much easier then ;)